# Azure search not handling hyphens in search queries properly

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

**If I search for:** 
712-645M4&searchMode=all&$count=true&queryType=full

I get 84 matches

**However, if I search for (note the quotes in the search term):**

"712-645M4"&searchMode=all&$count=true&queryType=full

I get 1 match (which is the expected result)

**According to the azure search documentation:**

[image]

So based on the docs it seems like there should be no need to enclose the hyphenated term between quotes (as long as there are no spaces before or after the hyphen)

Can you guys let me know if I am missing something when you have a chance? :)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting different results because the query is getting analyzed differently when you use quotes. Without the quotes, **712-645M4** would be analyzed to ‘**712**’ and ‘**645M4**’, whereas when you used quotes, **"712-645M4"** would be analyzed as a phrase.

You can verify this by using the [Analyze Text API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to see how different text is getting analyzed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nati. Is this the expected behavior though? Based on the documentation it seems that if there are no spaces wi-fi should be analyzed as a single term. Also, in my opinion it would make more sense to treat it as a single term as opposed to two different ones since most of the times hyphenated words are used as a unit that cease to make sense if they are broken down into individual terms. wi-fi is a good example for this.

Comment: My biggest confusion is that it seems to be breaking the searchMode=all contract as it's no longer requiring both terms  712  and 645M4 in the matches that it returns